# Cannot convert value of type '[String]?' to expected argument type 'String'

Tags: swift

What I want to do is set the image of `firstCard` to be equal to the image file with the name corresponding to `firstCardString`.

For instance, in the case below, the code could be setting `self.firstCard.image` to show the image named "card1" if it randomly picks it (I've clipped the rest of the array for brevity, the full thing contains 52 objects).

```
var deckArray = [
        "card1": ["Bear","Ball"],
        "card2": ["Bear","Ball"],
        "card3": ["Bear","Ball"],
        "card4": ["Bear","Ball"],
        "card5": ["Bear","Ball"],
        "card6": ["Bear","Ball"],
        "card7": ["Bear","Ball"],
]

    let firstRandomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(52))+1
    let firstCardString = deckArray["card\(firstRandomNumber)"]
    self.firstCard.image = UIImage(named: firstCardString)
```

Instead, I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[String]?' to expected argument type 'String'

I'm not entirely sure what this error message means, what is `[String]?`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[]` is an array, and `?` is an optional. Your `firstCardString` is not a string at all, but an optional array of strings. You've read the `deckArray` dictionary's value for that card, you see, and so your `firstCardString` actually looks something like this: `Optional(["Bear", "Ball"])`. I think you meant:

```
self.firstCard.image = UIImage(named: "card\(firstRandomNumber)")
```

This will set the image based on strings like `"card1"` or `"card4"`. I assume you'll use your dictionary for something else, later. When you do, be sure to unwrap the optional value it returns:

```
if let cardArray = deckArray["card\(firstRandomNumber)"] {
    //do something with bears and balls
}
```

Alternatively, consider making `deckArray` an array (which will make the name more reasonable), rather than a dictionary. Then you won't have to deal with optionals and will be able to access items as follows:

```
let cardArray = deckArray[firstRandomNumber]
//do something with bears and balls
```

Comment: But if I use `self.firstCard.image = UIImage(named: "card\(firstRandomNumber)")`, won't that attempt to set firstCard to an image name which is just a random number between 1 and 52, rather than setting it to the key ("card4") that corresponds to the index with that number?

Comment: The image name will be "card1" or "card3" or "card5". See the word "card" there in the name? It's followed by `\(firstRandomNumber)`, which will insert the number right after the word "card".

Comment: @andyvn22 please answer the same related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733225/cannot-convert-the-value-of-type-string-to-expected-argument-type-string

Answer (score 3):

Your deckArray is a Dictionary, and your firstCardString is an Array.

```
String = String

[String] = Array of strings.
```

Comment: please answer the similar related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733225/cannot-convert-the-value-of-type-string-to-expected-argument-type-string

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `deckArray` is in fact, a dictionary of arrays of strings. Therefore if `firstRandomNumber = 1`, `deckArray["card\(firstRandomNumber)"]` will return `["Bear","Ball"]`. That is definitely not a string!

Comment: please answer the similar related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733225/cannot-convert-the-value-of-type-string-to-expected-argument-type-string